# is ther such a software tool can display tasks on desktop

Tags: windows-7

To show my personal tasks on desktop, is there  such a tool  on windows seven ?

I googled a lot, found nothing

Comment: Where your tasks are lying? What type of task are those?

Answer (score 0):

[Desktop iCalendar Lite](http://www.desksware.com/desktop-icalendar-lite.htm) can sync with Google Tasks, and show the task list on the desktop.